# What algorithm to use for fitting several different lines

Tags: regression, classification, clustering, linear

I have a unique problem I'm not sure how to approach.

I have some data. The data was generated by a function that's basically $k$ different lines ($k$ may or may not be given).

Example:[image: function data was drawn from]

However, since the data is noisy or poorly measured, it doesn't look exactly like $k$ lines when I see it, and it's certainly not labelled. In-fact what I see is this:

[image: Data]

My goal is to label each point in this data and assign it to a different line. For instance, in this case, I would like something akin to this:

[image: Goal]

So this is a variant of clustering problem, where I know for certain that the shape of the cluster has to be almost a straight line.

I tried using k-means and had terrible results, I tried using mixture of Gaussians and saw significant improvement but nothing to write home about.

I am open to new suggestions, I'm unsure what to do.

download link for data sample - https://easyupload.io/deumkr

the column time received is the x-axis, the column tcptimestamp is the y-axis

Comment: The appropriate model would be a *linear spline* model, or *piecewise regression*. If I understand you correctly, the breakpoints (i.e., the x values where the slopes change) are not given, correct? Then they would need to be detected. There are tools that can do so. Can you edit your post to include (some of) your data?

Comment: the breakpoints are not given. The problem is exactly how to detect them. Once they are detected, it's a simple matter to find the straight lines (its not strictly speaking linear regression, since i have a constraint i have not mentioned, but safe to say the problem is solved once I find the breakpoints). What do you mean by including the data? as in a download link to the data file?

Comment: Yes, a download link to a csv file would work fine. Or simply paste them into the post.

Comment: @StephanKolassa done.

Comment: If you take the derivative of the data, it should be very easy to cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what [the `segmented` package for R](https://cran.r-project.org/package=segmented) finds if we ask it to find a single break point:

[image: plot]

R code:

```
foo <- read.table("noisy data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",dec=".")
library(segmented)

# model without breaks as a starting point
model.0 <- lm(TcpTimeStamp~Time.received,data=foo)

# model with one break
model.1 <- segmented(model.0,npsi=1)
plot(model.1,lwd=2,col="red")
with(foo,points(Time.received,TcpTimeStamp,pch=19,cex=0.8,col="grey"))
```

You can control the number of breaks to be detected by changing the `npsi` parameter to `segmented()`, or alternatively specify a vector of initial break locations with the `psi` parameter. Depending on your needs, you can change pick a number of breaks that makes sense visually, or base the decision on adjusted $R^2$ or AIC or similar, or even use cross-validation.

Take a look at the help page with `?segmented` (or read the documentation at the CRAN page linked above) for more parameters and pointers to literature for the algorithm used.

There are a number of short tutorials online that may be useful, e.g., [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/unraveling-spline-regression-in-r-937626bc3d96). You can also google for "linear spline", "breakpoint detection", "piecewise linear regression" or similar search terms.